# How to Create a Transparent over another View in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create a Transparent view upon my activity. The activity gets displayed on the click  of a tab. What i want is once i click any image in my activity at that time a transparent view gets overlayed upon the activity but my Tabs remain clickable. Also when the Transparent view gets created then background items of the activity should not be clickable. Is it possible?
And how will be able to achieve this in android?

Answer (score 2):

```
    //test.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows the overlayed image to pass through clicks to any buttons under it:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:clickable="false"
    ...
    />
```

(And when its set to **`true`**, the ImageView takes all the clicks)